# Javascript undefined error yet console log shows the values

Tags: javascript

Im trying to run this code with no success. I cant find what is causing this undefined error. Im really confused what am i doing wrong! Please have a look on this one and may you help me.

```
var inbox_items = function(){
        for (var i = start; i < limit; i++)
        {               
            var inbox = data[i];
            console.log(inbox);
            li = li+'<div class="list-group-item">'+
                    '<div class="row">'+
                        '<div class="col-md-1"><input type="checkbox"/></div>'+
                        '<a href="" style="text-decoration:none">'+
                        '<div class="col-md-5">'+inbox.msg_email+'</div>'+
                        '<div class="col-md-2">'+inbox.msg_subject+'</div>'+
                        '<div class="col-md-1">'+inbox.msgStatus_id+'</div>'+
                        '<div class="col-md-3">'+inbox.msg_date+" "+inbox.msg_time+'</div>'+
                        '</a>'+
                    '</div>'+
                  '</div>';             
        }
        return li;
    }

    switch(action)
    {
        case 'sentItems': $('#list_msgboxlist_msgbox').append(sent_items);                              
                            break;
        default: $('#list_msgbox').append(inbox_items);                     
                    break;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: i added a screenshot on this one. where is it gone to? Well anyways the screenshot is just the console that shows the error and the result of "console.log(inbox);".

Comment: Rather than a screen shot, can't you copy paste the error in your question?

Comment: Did you mean `.append(inbox_items())`?

Comment: What are the values of *start, limit* and *data*?

Comment: `limit` must be less or equal `data.length`.

Comment: this fixed my error:

  if(start.length > 10) start = 10;
  paint(0, start.length, records, action);

Comment: ill just change start to end for more clarification sorry

Comment: if(limit.length > 10)
  {
   limit = 10;
  }else{
   limit = limit.length;
  }
  paint(0, limit, records, action);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the length of `data` does not match the `limit`, so you end up with a `data[i]` of undefined, or you have undefined elements in your data.

Maybe use:

```
if(!inbox) continue;
```

Comment: lol i just discovered my mistake! so annoying!!!! anyways your correct. thanks for the feedback. I was overshooting my loop thats why it's giving me undefined error.

Answer (score 0):

**inbox** is undefined because of array **data** have a undefined element
You can just skip the undefined element like this

```
if(data[i] == undefined) continue;
var inbox = data[i];
console.log(inbox);
```